# range of a continuous function by drawing graphs

Tags: calculus

Continuous function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$, $f(0)=0,$ $f'(0)=0$, $0\leq f''(x)\leq 1$,

what is the possible range of $f$? I could see $[0,0.5]$ by drawing graphs but couldn't come up with a rigorous argument. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a more rigorous argument let's consider the worst-case scenario: $f''(x)=1$. This gives $f'(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}$. So $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Indeed we have
\begin{align*}
f(1)&=\int^{1}_{0}f'(x)dx+f(0)=\int^{1}_{0}\int^{x}_{0}f''(y)dy+f'(0)dx\\
&\leq \int^{1}_{0}\int^{x}_{0}1dy\ dx=[\frac{1}{2}x^{2}]^{1}_{0}=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer! Just a question, do you mean + f(0) on the RHS of the first equality?

Comment: Yes, in both cases. I'll change it in the answer.